# How to prove: there exists some $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ with $f=\lambda \text{Id}_{V}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem says:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimmensional vector spave over $\mathbb{F}$  and $f:V \rightarrow V$. Show that if with respect to all bases $f$ is represented by the same matrix $A$, then there exists some $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ with $f=\lambda \text{Id}_{V}$.

Because $f(\vec{v})=\lambda \vec{v}$ for all $\vec{v} \in V$ (i.e. $f=\lambda\text{Id}_V$) is equivalent to for all basis $B=\langle {\vec{\beta}_1, \dots, \vec{\beta}_n} \rangle $ for $V$, $f(\vec{\beta}_i)=\lambda\vec{\beta}_i$ with $i=1,\dots, n$. Then I am trying to reach the last part but I get stuck. Is it the correct aproach? Can you give me a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

1. Suppose, in the first basis $f(\vec{v})=\vec{v}A$ for every $\vec{v}$.
2. Take the second basis such that $\vec{v}$ becomes $\vec{v}M$
3. Consider the equation from 1: the vectors in the second basis have become $f(\vec{v}M)=\vec{v}AM$, on the other hand, we know that $f$ in the new basis is represented by the same matrix, so $f(\vec{v}M)=\vec{v}MA$.

So that $AM=MA$ for every $M$ such that $\det M\neq 0$.